# Read and write to file, but overwrites the file

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work. All the files which are shown actually exist. The 'logging.toString()' is a .txt file and it reads all the text in the logging and writes it back with the String which I want to be added. Although when I do this, it overwrites it. But I dont want that. Help?

```
    try{
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(logging.toString());
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        FileInputStream fstreams = new FileInputStream(logging);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstreams));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            htmlTextArea = htmlTextArea + strLine + "\n";
        }
        out.write(htmlTextArea + logto);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex){}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't it? You don't pass an append flag:

[FileWriter(String filename, boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

The API docs are your friend; they're often helpful for understanding behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(logging.toString());
```

to

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(logging.toString(), true);
```

That way, you tell Java you wish to APPEND the file. There's more in the Javadocs for FileWriter.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the way `FileWriter` is implemented.

If you want to append, you should use a different constructor: [`new FileWriter( logging.toString(), true );`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add something to file but not overwrite it use

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(logging.toString(),true);
```